# Showing that there is no Left splitting in the following exact sequence of groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Here is the exact sequence of groups I am asking about:

$$0 \to A_3 \xrightarrow{f} S_3 \xrightarrow{g} \mathbb Z/ 2 \mathbb Z \to 0$$

I want to show that there is no $\psi:  S_3 \to A_3 $ such that $\psi \circ f = 1_{A_3}.$

**My thoughts are:**

Any map to $3$ elements that is not zero is onto **(I do not remember how to prove this statement or exactly from where I learned it but I am sure it is correct, so if anyone can help me in proving it, I would appreciate this)** so we have a kernel. But the kernel of $S_3$ has $6$ elements while the Kernel of $A_3$ has 2 elelments. But then how can I reach that there is no such map? could someone help me please?

**EDIT**

I studied this theorem but I still can not see how it leads to a counter example:

**Theorem**

For groups $G,H,K,$  the following conditions are equivalent.

1. $G \cong K \times H.$
2. There exists a split short exact sequence: $1 \rightarrow K \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1.$
3. There exists a left-split short exact sequence: $1 \rightarrow K \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1.$
4. $H \triangleleft G, K \triangleleft G, G = HK $ and $H \cap K = \{1\}.$

Can anyone clarify this to me please?

Comment: A homomorphism can have a kernel, but not a group ("the kernel of $S_3$").

Comment: By Theorem 3.2 of [these notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/splittinggp.pdf), if there were such a $\psi$, then $S_3$ would be isomorphic to $A_3 \times (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$, but $A_3 \times (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$ is abelian and $S_3$ is not.

Comment: "These" notes are the notes by Keith Conrad, which are very helpful for this topic. It is worth to take time for reading (probably better invested time than posting here).

Comment: @azif00 is not there an answer without this theorem?

Comment: I do not see why $A_3 \times (\mathbb Z/ 2 \mathbb Z)$ is abelian .... could you clarify this please? @azif00

Comment: @MathIgnorance $A_3$ has order $3$, right? So, is cyclic, hence abelian. Therefore $A_3 \times (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$ is abelian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any homomorphism $S_3\to A_3$ maps all transpositions to the identity, since the only element in $A_3$ whose square is $1$ is $1$ itself. Now, every element of $S_3$ is equal to a product of transpositions, so...

Comment: So $S_3$ is abelian which is not ..... is this the correct completion you are asking about?

Comment: I do not understand your first sentence at all, an you explain why is this correct?

Comment: I got you for your last comment. but still I do not know how to complete "so ..."  can you please explain to me so what?

Comment: That means that all the homomorphisms will give us identity on $S_3$ right?

Comment: That means we can never get $A_3$ right ?

Comment: but for the map $f$ to have an inverse it must have a left (means f injective ) and right inverse ( means f surjective) right?

Comment: I mean $A_3$ is 3 elements and the image of any homomorphism is just the identity ... right? so we can not get any nonidentity element in $A_3$ right?

Comment: In the comment before last of me, I meant $\psi$ does not exist because f is neither sujective nor injective .... right?

Comment: Oh, but what we have is a group homomorphism and not a ring homomorphism .... Is my argument regarding the inverses correct?

Comment: What is the kernel of the map from $S_3$ to $A_3$

Comment: What is the kernel of the map What is the kernel of the map from $S_3$ to $\mathbb Z/ 2 Z$ ? I think if there were map $\psi$ then the sdimensions of the kernels should add to $6$ which can not happen but I need to show this.